# Cannot get objects to spawn on unity client (new system), Platform: Android, wifi

Tags: c#, android, networking, unity-game-engine, wifi

I have worked through several step-by-step examples on how to do this. But at the point where their programs create objects that sync with the server, mine does not. It sometimes looks like it links, server is initialized as is the client but the object never shows on the other phone. And yes they are on the same network and are running the same program. I am using Unity 5.3.1

I have already:
-- Created a Network manager
-- added a NetworkmanagerHUD
-- Added networkid and networktransform to the object

-- I also tried NetworkDiscovery

Messed with all the above and the spawning prefab. Im not sure I'm allowed to put a screenshot here so im throwing it out there like this. I am stumped. Please help.

[my editor screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6OR8.png)

now about the gamescreen. Im not sure of which button I should hit first but it can't be as simple as starting server starting client. Maybe this is the problem?

[My Screen that won't load the client scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6OR8.png)

Comment: just use RPC commands to send a text message from the "clients" to the "server", and see if those are working to begin with.  Just like in normal programming, Debug.Log is your friend...

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you trying to spawn player objects, or just any prefabs?
2. If you are spawning players, did you set "Player Prefab" on the NetworkManager and check "Auto Create Player", or do you try to spawn them in a custom way?
3. Also, if you are spawning players, did you check "Local Player Authority" on the NetworkIdentity on the player prefab?
4. Are the (player or other) prefabs registered with the NetworkManager? (if you open the "Spawn Info" foldout there is a collection of "Registered Spawnable Prefabs")
5. Does it work if you build a Standalone PC version of the client and connect with the Editor? (they can run side by side)
6. If the problem is the same with standalone PC and Editor, are there any errors or warnings in the Editor? (try it both with Editor as server and with Editor as client)

Comment: thank you for your attention. I am trying to spawn a simple playerobject

Comment: Sorry. 1 - i am trying to spawn a simple playerobject that i registered as a prefab in the heirarchy.                                                                                                                 2 - I used the autocreate player and I registered the prefab also in the nwmanager          3- Yes I set the localplayerauthority on the players nwid           4  - Yes the prefab (only one) is registered                      5 - I dont know it is an android build and i cannot convert it                  6 - I really cant change the build again, it was such a headache the first time

Comment: I may have a lead on how to do this. I just updated the question with the screen captures. THis might shed some light?...

Comment: It looks like you are trying to spawn "Planet (clone)" before the network server was started. The Server only starts when you either select "LAN Host" or "LAN Server". Only after the server is started, operations like SpawnObject will work. But I assume "Planet (clone)" is not the player object, so you probably have more issues than that.

Comment: I **strongly** suggest you get the PC version running as well. You can make a backup copy of your project beforehand if you're feeling uncomfortable. You will face many, many more problems with Network once you proceed with development, and being able to test both server and client in the Editor is an almost essential tool to tackle those problems.

Comment: ok. I will do a pc version. How do i spawn after the server is up? I have the source code for most of the networking scripts. WIll they still work if i modify them? Some scripts I have edited did not.

Comment: BTW i just realised that I could extend the Networking scripts. Is this wise/necessary?

Comment: Well, of course you **can** do everything. I myself found extending the NetworkManager to be a very tricky business, with things sometimes not working out at all. If you want to do stuff after the Server is set up, the easiest thing might be to assign an "Online scene" to the NetworkManager. This scene will be loaded after server is set up and running. If you have any scripts in that scene, they are guaranteed to run only after the connection is established. You may find that you are unable to assign a scene to the NetworkManager. If so, go to Build Settings and add the scene there first.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Hilbert. Unfortunately although the online scene appears on the server/host, nothing appears on the client. I know that all objects must be registered and spawned but not even the players will spawn now. not even on the server. Should I have a new Networkmanager on the online scene (i currently do). Why is nothing spawning? Should I explore the advanced options on the network manager? If so, what should the timeouts be?

Comment: Don't have a new NetworkManager in the Online scene, but check "Dont destroy on load" for the one in your startup scene. Apart from that, make sure you are using standard, unmodified Network code, and check the errors/warnings on server and client. That's where you need the running PC version. Also, make sure to select "LAN Host" to start your server. Only a Host will have an own Player, a simple Server won't.

Comment: Hello again.  I did what you said, but still no spawning on either phone. I would like to send you a screenshot, but I dont know how on this site. I was using LAN host, and it looks like it works, the client ready button is there and the port is 7777. but no spawning of anything on the other phone, and the player doesn't spawn on either.  It will take me a long time to get the pc version up and running.

Comment: it won't let me post any more screen shots

Comment: Sorry. The screenshot is up there now

Comment: There is an error shown on your screenshot. Is this a relict from an earlier stage of development, or does the player prefab indeed have no NetworkIdentity (it should have!!)? If your project is so hard to migrate, why not make an empty project and get things running **on the PC** there with the least amount of assets and code necessary. Once it's working there, test on Android. And once that works, too, move on from there, step by step, adding assets and code from your current project to the new - working - one, and solve problems as they appear.

Comment: I did it. Then when I port it to android, nothing appears on the client screen. Please advise. Ive been trying this for a long time

Comment: First of all, make sure the object isn't simply off screen. Second, check the Android device's logs. You can do that by typing "adb logcat" in the Command line in your Android-SDK\platform-tools folder. This will yield an immense number of log lines and continue to print new ones as they appear. If you now start the client on the device, you'll see all Unity's debug output (Warnings, Errors, Debug.Log etc.) This should get you on your way.

Comment: Oh, and the device has to be connected to your PC via USB for adb to work. This may require special drivers, depending on your device.
And "USB debugging" must be enabled on the device. You can find them in the Developer settings.

Comment: Listen, thanks again for sticking with me on this one. But it seems that the client doesnt even change to the online scene. I should have spotted this earlier. Do you know what would cause this? The  Network Discovery component seems to me to be an obvious solution, so I will try that now, until I have a better suggestion, because it sometimes gives me a button that says gameat::66:55.. etc. But i click it and nothing happens. Just like the client ready button. If that fails I will wade through the adb readout. What do you think?

Comment: adb has unbelievably given me some interesting info. apparently the following is true;

Comment: r$OnPermissionsChangedListener;'
W/dalvikvm(21475): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/j/c;' failed
D/dalvikvm(21475): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x363b at 0x02 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/j/b;.a
D/dalvikvm( 2513): GC_CONCURRENT freed 947K, 57% free 10374K/23860K, paused 15ms+4ms, total 90ms
D/dalvikvm( 2513): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 70ms
D/dalvikvm( 2513): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 71ms
D/dalvikvm( 2513): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 73ms
D/dalvikvm(21585): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6057K, 44% free 8964K/15744K, paused 19ms+55ms, total 259ms
D/dalvikvm(215

Comment: also : I/ActivityManager(  886): Killing 21056:com.sec.android.gallery3d/u0a39 (adj 15): empty #14
E/dalvikvm(21585): Could not find class 'android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager', referenced from method com.cleanmaster.applocklib.b.b.J
W/dalvikvm(21585): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 57 (Landroid/app/usage/UsageStatsManager;) in Lcom/cleanmaster/applocklib/b/b;
D/dalvikvm(21585): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000f
E/dalvikvm(21585): Could not find class 'android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager', referenced from method com.cleanmaster.applocklib.b.b.b
W/dalvikvm(21585): VFY: unable to resolve

Comment: Android logging will produce lots and lots of output that "looks" serious but does not concern you in the least. Every message has a process number, like "I/ActivityManager (%procNum%): bla". When starting the client, the log should produce output that is definately from Unity. Once you identified one of these messages, you know Unity's current process number and can identitfy messages that come from Unity. You should ignore any messages that are not from Unity. I can not give you more specifics as I don't have an Android device ready to test it.

Comment: o no. Any ideas why the scene isen't loading? Im putting another screenshot up.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a fortune teller. Please do the work, find the relevant log output and try to make sense of it. Read documentation and use google if necessary. And if any **specific** questions arise you can ask them here, giving all the information that may be relevant for the reader. Get it running on PC, then port to Android. If it doesn't work there it should give you log output that tells you why, making the fix trivial often enough.

Comment: Hello again. I actually got some nice output from adb. The magic phrase was:  adb logcat -s Unity > output.txt.         This showed me that the scenemanager was erroneously loading a scene and that one of my objects had two networkidentities. Alas then it started giving me blank files with only the following: --------- beginning of /dev/log/system

--------- beginning of /dev/log/main. Im doing more adb type research currently. So thank you for setting me straight. And if you have any more ideas I would love to hear them.

Comment: hey. i re-asked the question using what progress we have made to make it more specific.